# Input modify URL Webview?

Tags: android, variables, android-activity, webview

users have an activity with an edittext and a button.
in the edittext they have to insert their login ID. and press go to display a other activity with webview loading the right site.

an example. this is the link i want users to visit .  www.example.com/time/id=***1***/type=student

if sombody enters a 2 in the edittext it wil open the times for student id 2 and so on.

this is what i have.

**LOGIN**

```
package com.beter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

Button go_btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

            go_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn);




      go_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });      
}
```

**and the layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/idfield"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/id"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/go_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idfield"
    android:text="@string/login" />
```

**The Webview Activity**

```
package com.beter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebActivity extends Activity  {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);


    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);


    webview.loadUrl("http://roosters.gepro-osi.nl/roosters/rooster.php?wijzigingen=1&leerling=116277&type=Leerlingrooster&afdeling=12-13_OVERIG&school=905");
}
}
```

**and again the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do i make the user input. display the good webview. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all get a reference to your edittext in your Login Activity as

```
 go_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn);
 ed_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittextid);
```

The change your onClick to

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("id", ed_txt.getText());
  LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Then retrive this id in your WebActivity onCreate as

```
String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
```

Then your url will be

```
String myURL = "www.example.com/time/id="+id+"/type=student";
```

Comment: my bad , change ed_txt.getText() to ed_txt.getText().toString();
Also did you input something inside your edit text?